# Permuting sum 2

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, summation

Consider the following:
$$\sum\limits_{s=0}^{z-1} \sum\limits_{j=0}^{s} \frac{z-s}{z-j} $$
How do I get to this? I know that the upper index of the inner sum is the new starting index. Then I can use, that the outer sum reaches $z-1$. But why change $s$ and $j$ location?

$$ \sum\limits_{s=0}^{z-1} \sum\limits_{j=s}^{z-1} \frac{z-j}{z-s} $$

Comment: What is $u$ in the first formula?

Comment: @AndréPorto: Sorry I changed it.

Comment: Interchange the order of the sums & then interchange the summation variables.

Comment: But why does the summation variable change location. You only change the order of summands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum\limits_{s=0}^{z-1} \sum\limits_{j=0}^{s} \frac{z-s}{z-j} &=& \sum\limits_{j=0}^{z-1} \sum\limits_{s=j}^{z-1} \frac{z-s}{z-j} \\
&=& \sum\limits_{S=0}^{z-1} \sum\limits_{J=S}^{z-1} \frac{z-J}{z-S} \\
\end{eqnarray*}